# If you call multiple BitmapImages at once, some of them get stuck in the download process, and the image won't be displayed in the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, data-binding, bitmapimage

I have multiple Images in my Window. Every single one of them download another image at the same time.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource cachedImgConv},IsAsync=True}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

Inside the Converter i download with a BitmapImage:

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
            image.UriSource = new Uri(uri);
            image.EndInit();

return image;
```

This works well so far. All images are downloaded and displayed in the UI. Unless the number of images reaches something like 20 and above. Then some BitmapImage get stuck in the download process.

I tried to use different CacheOptions and CreateOptions from the BitmapImage.
To use in Xaml "IsAsync" true and false.

Comment: Are the BitmapImages loaded from web resources or local image files?

Comment: From a web resource

Comment: That is not reproducible. I can easily download a lot more images like this. I even do this without a converter, because the Image.Source property already provides conversion from string and Uri out of the box. Setting IsAsync is also pointless here.

Comment: I have found the problem. All images came from the same server. After a certain number of requests, it simply refused the connection. I have now implemented the functionality by outsourcing the downloads to a task queue, which fetches the images one after other.
Thanks for the quick help :)